# Where do I put the specific translation functions in Django App?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project in which I have changed the default 'Django Administration' text in the header.
Now I have implemented translation of strings that django knows about, but I cannot figure out how to translate this title.
I put the translation function in models.py but it doesn't change when I change Language.
I've edited the base.html template like so
{% trans 'My Console' %}
And added the msgstr in my .po files and ran makemessages and compilemessages
I am running out of things to try.
Can anyone shed some light on how to do this?
I can supply code if it will help.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your app name up to admin app in your INSTALLED_APPS settings.py tuple.

Comment: I believe I've done that like so:`INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'DonationsAdmin',
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
    
)`

Comment: Do you have edit the .po files of your app or those of admin app?

Comment: I've edited the .po files of my app but not the admin app which is where exactly?

Comment: Yes it's ok.
Maybe your problem is that you don't have selected the current language? For language selection have you used translated urls or cookies?

Comment: I change the language by clicking a link in the base.html footer  `csrf_token %}
 <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
 <input type="hidden" name="language" value="{{ lang.0 }}" />
<a href="#" rel="nofollow" onclick="document.setLang{{ lang.1 }}.submit(); return false;">{{ lang.1 }}</a>`

Comment: Do you ave added 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware' in your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in settings.py ?